# mypy 0.942 rejects 'match' only on Linux?

Tags: python, linux, mypy, python-typing

*mypy* 0.942 judges this program correct on Mac OS 12.2.1 but rejects the second line as a syntax error on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
e = 'a'
match e:
    case name if isinstance(e, str):
        print('name', e)
    case x if isinstance(e, int):
        print('int', e)
```

I'm running the same command on both systems:

```
mypy --python-version 3.10 x.py
```

Am I doing something wrong or should I report this as a bug?

I do not have a `mypy.ini` file. I tried deleting the `.mypy_cache` directory and got the same result.

---

Here's the output with the `-v` (verbose) flag on:

```
$ mypy --python-version 3.10 -v --python-executable /home/bkovitz/local/bin/python3.10 x.py 
LOG:  Could not load plugins snapshot: @plugins_snapshot.json

LOG:  Mypy Version:           0.942
LOG:  Config File:            Default
LOG:  Configured Executable:  /home/bkovitz/local/bin/python3.10
LOG:  Current Executable:     /usr/bin/python3
LOG:  Cache Dir:              .mypy_cache
LOG:  Compiled:               True
LOG:  Exclude:                []
LOG:  Found source:           BuildSource(path='x.py', module='x', has_text=False, base_dir='/home/bkovitz/stuff')
LOG:  Could not load cache for x: x.meta.json
LOG:  Metadata not found for x
LOG:  Parsing x.py (x)
LOG:  Bailing due to parse errors
LOG:  Build finished in 0.011 seconds with 0 modules, and 1 errors
x.py:2: error: invalid syntax  [syntax]
Found 1 error in 1 file (errors prevented further checking)
```

I see that `Current Executable` is wrong: that's a Python 3.6.9 (needed for Ubuntu). That `python3` is not the first one in the `PATH`. The first `python3` in the `PATH` is in the same directory as the `Configured Executable` and is Python 3.10.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the shebang line in the *mypy* script invoked the wrong `python3` executable. I changed the first line of `~/local/bin/mypy` from this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

to this:

```
#!/home/bkovitz/local/bin/python3
```

and it worked. The latter is Python 3.10, which presumably has a parser that can make an AST for the `match` statement, unlike Python 3.6.9.

I also had to run `hash -r` at the shell prompt. The shell had cached the previous version of the `mypy` script, so editing the file had no effect (!).

Comment: The shebang is an artifact of how `mypy` was installed. You might want to try using `python -m mypy ...` instead, or install `mypy` into a virtual environment configured  with the appropriate version of Python.